# Function sum with first value for 3 times instead of other 2 values

Tags: c++

I want the code to sum up all three numbers with the loop but the function just sum up the total amount with the first value for three times please help.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class TEST
{
    int num;
public:
    void input()
    {
        cin>>num;
    }
    int getAmount()
    {
        return num;
    }
};
float getTotalAmount(TEST *obj)
{
    static float totalamount=0;
    totalamount = totalamount + obj->getAmount();
    return totalamount;
}
int main()
{
    TEST obj[3];

    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
    cout<<"Enter Number["<<i+1<<"]:";
    obj[i].input();
    cout<<"Current total= "<<getTotalAmount(obj)<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please be more clear in writing the question. It is difficult to interpret.

Comment: maybe you should change it to ```cout<<"Current total= "<<getTotalAmount(&obj[i])<<endl;```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have an array, like

```
TEST obj[3];
```

using just the array name like `obj` makes it decay to a pointer to its *first* element.

So in the loop you are calling `getTotalAmount` with a pointer to the same object (`obj[0]`) all the time.

If you want to call the function for the different objects, either use `&obj[i]` or `obj + i`.

Answer (score 1):

`getTotalAmount(obj)`, you're passing the address of the 1st element every time. Change it to:

```
cout<<"Current total= "<<getTotalAmount(&obj[i])<<endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your line

```
cout<<"Current total= "<<getTotalAmount(obj)<<endl;
```

to

```
cout<<"Current total= "<<getTotalAmount(&obj[i])<<endl;
```

and you will pass the pointer to each element, not just to the first one.

Answer (score 1):

```
cout<<"Current total= "<<getTotalAmount(obj)<<endl;
```

in this statement everytime you are sending obj, which evaluted as obj+0 -> &obj[0] which is first object of type TEST.

That is the reason it is taking first obj num value for 3 times.

you can correct it as

```
cout<<"Current total= "<<getTotalAmount(&obj[i])<<endl;
```

or

```
cout<<"Current total= "<<getTotalAmount(obj+i)<<endl;
```

Answer (score -2):

The problem is with your `for loop` in the `main` function. Instead of

```
for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
{
cout<<"Enter Number["<<i+1<<"]:";
obj[i].input();
cout<<"Current total= "<<getTotalAmount(obj)<<endl;
}
```

You should use

```
for(int i=0;i<=3;i++)
{
cout<<"Enter Number["<<i+1<<"]:";
obj[i].input();
cout<<"Current total= "<<getTotalAmount(obj)<<endl;
}
```

or

```
for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
{
cout<<"Enter Number["<<i<<"]:";
obj[i].input();
cout<<"Current total= "<<getTotalAmount(obj)<<endl;
}
```

Comment: The middle code-snippet will go out of bounds of the array. The last snippet is really no different than the first, you just print another number. Neither solves the problem, and one even introduces other problems.

Comment: When posting something that you think is a solution, you should explain why you think it is.